# How to strip the first few characters of an input stream in java?

Tags: java, xml, inputstream, java-io

I have a fileInputStream object that may or may not contain xml declaration `<?xml version='1.0'?>`.  I need to strip the xml declaration if it exists.  How do I do that without converting the inputStream object into string, stripping the XML PI and then converting it back to input stream?

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(importFilePath);
```

Comment: this is not xml processing instruction, it is called xml declaration... it could contain vital info about the xml, such as encoding type, without which the data may become invalid... is this what you really wan to do?

Comment: You are correct. Its not a PI.  I referred to it as PI because, in my scenario, I had to append <import> at the beginning of the input stream and </import> at the end of steam and I need to pass the resultant stream to org.w3c.dom.Document.parse().  The parse method was throwing an exception saying "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: processing instructions must not start with xml".  The exception was pointing to the beginning of the XML declaration and saying PI must not start with xml.

Comment: Yes.  My goal is to strip out the xml declaration from the inputStream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the `FileInputStream` in a [PushbackInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html), and check to see if it starts with a PI.  If so, then read it out.  Otherwise, push back the characters you read to test it.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options:

1. Use [FileInputStream.getChannel()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#getChannel--). After reading from the channel, you can invoke `position(0)` if needed to reset it to the beginning.
2. Use a custom [FilteredInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) to wrap the InputStream. This can be written in such a way that the first line is buffered in advance, to determine if it will be used or discarded.

Comment: As noted by @MattTimmermans, there is an available FilteredInputStream implementation which can serve this purpose mentioned in #2 (PushbackInputStream). However it maintains a continuous buffer, not just the initial line.